# why is index.php added to URLs?

Tags: 9, uri

Since I updated my site to Drupal 9.5.11, 'index.php/' is added to every URL: `http://mysite.org/index.php/` for the home page, for example.

On some page, I have a list with links to files and, because of this strange behavior, links lead to a 'Page not found' error. In this case, 'index.php/' is even added twice: `http://mysite.org/index.php/index.php/system/files/contracts/Contract-228-20231108.pdf`.

I found some posts about similar issues but the main difference with these posts is that in my case, the behavior occurs when the user is authenticated. No problem for anonymous visitors!

Other clue (maybe?): it occurs in my Production site and everything is OK on my local site (managed with MAMP).

Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is floating core bug. See [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3050261)

The answer which helps me:

Install [redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module and enable "Enforce clean and canonical URLs" then clear cache.

Comment: Installed Redirect and it seems to work. Thanks!